# How do I target only elements that are followed by another (specific) element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some code that is generated by a Drupal view. It looks like this (stripped down for clarity):

```
<div class="group_content">
  <h3>Header Link</h3>
  <div class="row odd">Here's some content</div>
  <h3>Another Header Link</h3>
  <div class="row even">Here's some more content</div>
</div>

<div class="group_content">
  <h3>Header Link 2</h3>
  <div class="row odd">Here's some content 2</div>
</div>
```

Because this is generated by a CMS, there's a limit to what I can do about the rendered code - for example, I can't add an even/odd class to the h3 elements.

How can I (in css) target only the `div class=row` that is followed by another `div class=row`? If there are more than one row in a group, I need to add a bottom border to the div to act as a visual separator. So, using my example code, there would be a border applied to `div class="row odd">Here's some content</div>` because it has another row following it.

I'm a backend developer, so CSS is not my strong suit. We do need to support IE7.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot assign css to `parent` based on `child`.You will need to use `javascript` for this purpose.

Comment: The relationship is not parent/child - the divs are not children of the h3, they just follow them.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've added a workaround though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Modified Logic

Since you need IE7 support, place the border on the `h3` element instead:

```
div.row + h3 {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

This will work in just about every modern browser, and IE7:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/BjUf9/1/

#### Explicit Subjects in Selectors

If you insist on placing it only on every `div.row` but the last, that's a different story. You're asking about moving the subject of a selector, which is not currently possible, but will be when browsers implement Level 4 selectors:

```
div.row! + div.row {
    /* These styles apply to the first div.row
       $div.row + div.row is another potential 
       syntax */
}
```

#### :last-child, in IE9+

Since you cannot do that, what you can do is set a style for all `div.row` elements, adding your border, and then overriding that for any `div.row:last-child` which will remove that border for any `div.row` that is the last element in its parent:

```
div.row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
div.row:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/BjUf9/

I should note that this will not work in IE7, unfortunately. But the modified logic presented in the first solution should take care of you there.

Comment: unfortunately `last-child` doesn't work on IE7 (while `first-child` works fine)

Comment: Was the WD updated, or are you basing your CSS4 answers off the ED now? (Things like the subject token are why I'm thinking of holding off from any mention of CSS4 in my answers henceforth...)

Comment: @F.Calderan You're right. I was thinking of the CSS 2.1 selectors. Edit forthcoming.

Comment: If it just doesn't display in IE7, we'll deal. As long as it doesn't cause anything else to break.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't recall which used `$` and which used `!`. I generally mention that both syntaxes are floating around.

Comment: @EmmyS I've updated the answer with a *better* approach, IMHO. Target any `h3` that follows a `div.row`, and add the border to the *top* of that, rather than to the *bottom* of the `div.row` it follows. Same effect, but the support exists in IE7.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - thank you! The modified logic worked. I really need to learn some more about css...

Answer (score 3):

you could revert the logic and apply a `border-top` to `.row + .row` elements

```
.row + .row {
   border-top : 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) works fine on `IE7+`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on ie7 and others

```
.row + h3 {
  border-top : 1px black solid;
}
```